# If every polynomial of degree 2 is reducible then $K$ is algebraically closed?

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, finite-fields

This [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1878348/if-every-polynomial-of-degree-2-and-odd-degree-has-a-root-in-kx-then-k) shows that if every polynomial of degree 2 and odd degree has a root in $K[X]$, then $K$ is algebraically closed.

I wonder what examples can I find to see that the condition "odd degree" is necessary so that I cannot prove the statement:

> Let $K$ be a field, if every polynomial of degree two is reducible
>   then $K$ is algebraically closed.

This [other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/93744/non-algebraically-closed-field-in-which-every-polynomial-of-degree-n-has-a-ro) seems to give a procedure.

If I start with $\mathbb{F}_p$ then I know that adding a root of an irreducible of degree two over $\mathbb{F}_p$ will give me:

1. $\mathbb{F}_{p^2}$ by Moore's theorem there is only one field of cardinality $p^2$.
2. Any other root of an irreducible of degree 2 over $\mathbb{F}_p$ must be here .

The problem is that I do not get the roots of irreducible over $\mathbb{F}_{p^2}$ and therefore this process has to be iterated obtaining at the end the union $\cup_{i \ge 1} \mathbb{F}_{p^{2^i}}$. This does not need to be a fieldso that I shoud take the minimal field over it $\langle \cup_{i \ge 1} \mathbb{F}_{p^{2^i}} \rangle$.

In $\cup_{i \ge 1} \mathbb{F}_{p^{2^i}}$, it is clear that there cannot be a root of an irreducible of degree $3$. However, in principle I could find such a root in $\langle \cup_{i \ge 1} \mathbb{F}_{p^{2^i}} \rangle$. Why is it not the case?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Actually, $\bigcup_{i \ge 1} \mathbb{F}_{p^{2^i}}$ is a field.  More generally, the union of any nested sequence of subfields $F_0\subseteq F_1\subseteq F_2\subseteq\dots$ is a field.  This is because every field axiom involves only finitely many elements at a time, and any finite set of elements will be contained in $F_n$ for some $n$.